# color and canvas implementations in Rust for Ray Tracer Challenge

Tags: performance, rust, graphics

I'm learning Rust by working through Jamis Buck's [*The Ray Tracer Challenge*](https://pragprog.com/book/jbtracer/the-ray-tracer-challenge). The book instructs the reader on what to build in what order, and provides all required test cases.

Included here are my implementations of 1) an RGB color representation, and 2) a canvas, which is essentially an editable 2-d array of color objects with plaintext PPM image printing capability.

My particular concerns are 1) how can this noob write more idiomatic Rust, and 2) can it be more performant, particularly for large canvases with millions of pixels?

color.rs:

```
use approx::AbsDiffEq;
use std::ops::Add;
use std::ops::Div;
use std::ops::Mul;
use std::ops::Sub;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Color {
    pub r: f32,
    pub g: f32,
    pub b: f32,
}

pub fn build_color(r: f32, g: f32, b: f32) -> Color {
    Color { r: r, g: g, b: b }
}

impl Add for Color {
    type Output = Color;
    fn add(self, other: Color) -> Color {
        Color {
            r: self.r + other.r,
            g: self.g + other.g,
            b: self.b + other.b,
        }
    }
}

impl Sub for Color {
    type Output = Color;
    fn sub(self, other: Color) -> Color {
        Color {
            r: self.r - other.r,
            g: self.g - other.g,
            b: self.b - other.b,
        }
    }
}

// scalar multiplication (commutative)
impl Mul<f32> for Color {
    type Output = Color;
    fn mul(self, scalar: f32) -> Color {
        Color {
            r: self.r * scalar,
            g: self.g * scalar,
            b: self.b * scalar,
        }
    }
}

// scalar multiplication (commutative)
impl Mul<Color> for f32 {
    type Output = Color;
    fn mul(self, color: Color) -> Color {
        color * self
    }
}

// scalar division
impl Div<f32> for Color {
    type Output = Color;
    fn div(self, scalar: f32) -> Color {
        Color {
            r: self.r / scalar,
            g: self.g / scalar,
            b: self.b / scalar,
        }
    }
}

// Multiplying two Color objects produces a mix of the two colors using the Hadamard product
impl Mul<Color> for Color {
    type Output = Color;
    fn mul(self, other: Color) -> Color {
        Color {
            r: self.r * other.r,
            g: self.g * other.g,
            b: self.b * other.b,
        }
    }
}

// required for equality tests because floating point numbers must be compared approximately
impl AbsDiffEq for Color {
    type Epsilon = f32;

    fn default_epsilon() -> Self::Epsilon {
        f32::default_epsilon()
    }

    fn abs_diff_eq(&self, other: &Self, epsilon: Self::Epsilon) -> bool {
        f32::abs_diff_eq(&self.r, &other.r, epsilon)
            && f32::abs_diff_eq(&self.g, &other.g, epsilon)
            && f32::abs_diff_eq(&self.b, &other.b, epsilon)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_adding_colors() {
        let c1 = build_color(0.9, 0.6, 0.75);
        let c2 = build_color(0.7, 0.1, 0.25);
        abs_diff_eq!(c1 + c2, build_color(1.6, 0.7, 1.0));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_subtracting_colors() {
        let c1 = build_color(0.9, 0.6, 0.75);
        let c2 = build_color(0.7, 0.1, 0.25);
        abs_diff_eq!(c1 - c2, build_color(0.2, 0.5, 0.5));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_multiply_color_by_scalar() {
        let c = build_color(0.2, 0.3, 0.4);
        abs_diff_eq!(c * 2.0, 2.0 * c);
        abs_diff_eq!(c * 2.0, build_color(0.4, 0.6, 0.8));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_mix_colors_by_multiplication() {
        let c1 = build_color(1.0, 0.2, 0.4);
        let c2 = build_color(0.9, 1.0, 0.1);
        abs_diff_eq!(c1 * c2, build_color(0.9, 0.2, 0.04));
    }
}
```

canvas.rs:

```
use crate::color::{build_color, Color};

pub struct Canvas {
    pub width: usize,
    pub height: usize,
    data: Vec<Vec<Color>>,
}

// Create a canvas initialized to all black
pub fn build_canvas(width: usize, height: usize) -> Canvas {
    Canvas {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        data: vec![vec![build_color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); width]; height],
    }
}

const MAX_COLOR_VAL: i16 = 255;
const MAX_PPM_LINE_LENGTH: usize = 70;
// length of "255" is 3
// TODO: this should be evaluated programmatically, but "no matching in consts allowed" error prevented this
const MAX_COLOR_VAL_STR_LEN: usize = 3;
impl Canvas {
    pub fn write_pixel(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, color: Color) -> () {
        self.data[y][x] = color;
    }

    pub fn pixel_at(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Color {
        self.data[y][x]
    }

    // scale/clamp color values from 0-1 to 0-255
    fn scale_color(&self, rgb: f32) -> u8 {
        (rgb * MAX_COLOR_VAL as f32)
            .min(MAX_COLOR_VAL as f32)
            .max(0.0) as u8
    }

    // If current line has no more room for more RGB values, add it to the PPM string and clear it;
    // otherwise, add a space separator in preparation for the next RGB value
    fn write_rgb_separator(&self, line: &mut String, ppm: &mut String) {
        if line.len() < MAX_PPM_LINE_LENGTH - MAX_COLOR_VAL_STR_LEN {
            (*line).push(' ');
        } else {
            ppm.push_str(&line);
            ppm.push('\n');
            line.clear();
        }
    }

    // Return string containing PPM (portable pixel map) data representing current canvas
    pub fn to_ppm(&self) -> String {
        let mut ppm = String::new();
        // write header
        ppm.push_str("P3\n");
        ppm.push_str(&(format!("{} {}\n", self.width, self.height)));
        ppm.push_str(&(format!("{}\n", MAX_COLOR_VAL)));

        // Write pixel data. Each pixel RGB value is written with a separating space or newline;
        // new rows are written on new lines for human reading convenience, but lines longer than
        // MAX_PPM_LINE_LENGTH must also be split.
        let mut current_line = String::new();
        for row in 0..self.height {
            current_line.clear();
            for (i, column) in (0..self.width).enumerate() {
                let color = self.pixel_at(column, row);
                let r = self.scale_color(color.r);
                let g = self.scale_color(color.g);
                let b = self.scale_color(color.b);

                current_line.push_str(&r.to_string());
                self.write_rgb_separator(&mut current_line, &mut ppm);

                current_line.push_str(&g.to_string());
                self.write_rgb_separator(&mut current_line, &mut ppm);

                current_line.push_str(&b.to_string());

                // if not at end of row yet, write a space or newline if the next point will be on this line
                if i != self.width - 1 {
                    self.write_rgb_separator(&mut current_line, &mut ppm);
                }
            }
            if current_line.len() != 0 {
                ppm.push_str(&current_line);
                ppm.push('\n');
            }
        }
        ppm
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_height_and_width() {
        let c = build_canvas(15, 10);
        assert_eq!(c.width, 15);
        assert_eq!(c.height, 10);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_write_and_read_pixels() {
        let mut canvas = build_canvas(10, 5);
        let color = build_color(0.1, 0.2, 0.3);
        canvas.write_pixel(7, 4, color);
        assert_eq!(canvas.pixel_at(7, 4), color);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_ppm_header() {
        let c = build_canvas(20, 5);
        let ppm = c.to_ppm();
        let mut lines = ppm.lines();
        assert_eq!(lines.next().unwrap(), "P3");
        assert_eq!(lines.next().unwrap(), "20 5");
        assert_eq!(lines.next().unwrap(), "255");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_ppm_pixel_data() {
        let mut c = build_canvas(5, 3);
        c.write_pixel(0, 0, build_color(1.5, 0.0, 0.0));
        c.write_pixel(2, 1, build_color(0.0, 0.5, 0.0));
        c.write_pixel(4, 2, build_color(-0.5, 0.0, 1.0));

        let ppm = c.to_ppm();
        let mut lines = ppm.lines();
        // ignore header
        lines.next();
        lines.next();
        lines.next();
        assert_eq!(lines.next().unwrap(), "255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0");
        // book says 128, but I'll trust Rust's rounding for now
        assert_eq!(lines.next().unwrap(), "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0");
        assert_eq!(lines.next().unwrap(), "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_splitting_long_ppm_lines() {
        let mut canvas = build_canvas(10, 2);
        let color = build_color(1.0, 0.8, 0.6);
        // TODO: maybe turn this into a function on canvas?
        for row in 0..canvas.height {
            for column in 0..canvas.width {
                canvas.write_pixel(column, row, color);
            }
        }
        let ppm = canvas.to_ppm();
        let mut lines = ppm.lines();
        // skip header
        lines.next();
        lines.next();
        lines.next();
        assert_eq!(
            lines.next().unwrap(),
            "255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204"
        );
        assert_eq!(
            lines.next().unwrap(),
            "153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153"
        );
        assert_eq!(
            lines.next().unwrap(),
            "255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204"
        );
        assert_eq!(
            lines.next().unwrap(),
            "153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153 255 204 153"
        );
    }
}
```

Permalink to current repository state: https://github.com/garfieldnate/ray_tracer_challenge/tree/e7fd5ebc2f6af209ea1db0f1ce3a04519bed7bf0

Comment: You can replace for 4 of use with one: `use std::ops::{Add,Div,Mul,Sub}`

Comment: `build_color` could be a called a `new` and be implemented inside `impl Color` block. This will allow you to crate `Color` with `Color::new()`. you cloud also provide a builder for color. `ColorBuilder::new().green(1f32).red(0.4f32).blue(0.2f32).build()` This will help people not accidentally mix red with blue.